# AXIOS post request - missing url param

Tags: reactjs, server, axios, backend, nodemailer

I set a react webpage that has is structured as follow:

```
MAIN PAGE www.localhost:3000.com, 
OTHER PAGES www.localhost:3000.com/services, www.localhost:3000.com/about, www.localhost:3000.com/contactMe.
```

I'm using axios from www.localhost:3000.com/contactMe to perform a post for a contact form that will send data thru my backend/nodemailer.

Using Postman to verify the post status, the post method is NOT working from `www.localhost:3000.com/contactMe/api/contact` and it works correctly for `localhost:3000/api/contact` and `localhost:5000/api/contact`.

How could I fix this Request failed with status code 404 from www.localhost:3000.com/contactMe/api/contact?

```
HOST: localhost:3000
SERVER: app.use('/api,...)
CONTROLLER: pouter.post('/contact',...)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to just use the base URL and send the POST request to `www.localhost:3000.com/api/contact` from any page.

So even if the user is on `www.localhost:3000.com/contactMe`, it still sends the request to `www.localhost:3000.com/api/contact`.

A quick way to get it is using `window.location.hostname`.

Another way is just putting a `/` in the beginning of the URL you're putting in your POST request `axios.post('/api/contact', ...)` and it should send it directly to `${baseURL}/api/contact` from any page